# What is the proper method of creating an object of a parent window using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, window, element

I have seen in researching how to create an object of an element's parent window at least two different ways of writing the code to do it using JQuery.

Which one of these are correct, and what is the difference in the first one versus the second one?

The purpose in trying to figure this out is that I want to set the size of an iFrame and position it within the parent window.

Thanks.

Example 1

```
var windowId = 'custErrWindow';
var parentWindow = $('#' + windowId).parent();
var height = parentWindow.height();
```

Example 2

```
var windowId = 'custErrWindow';
var parentWindow = $('#' + windowId).parent.$('#window');
var height = parentWindow.height();
```

Comment: Which one of them works? i can guarantee example2 doesn't work, `$().parent` is a function not an object. Example1 doesn't seem to be doing anything that would be targeting a parent or child window.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no `.parent` property of objects that jQuery returns, but maybe someone with more knowledge can correct me on this -- so that would make your `$('#' + windowId).parent` undefined. In terms of the right way to find a parent element, check jQuery's docs for `parent()` vs. `parents()`; for example, `parent()` of an `HTML` tag element will return a set with `document`, while `parents()` does not. Hope that helps.

Comment: You're correct.  According to the JQuery docs, .parent() does not return an object, it "returns a set containing document."  I will edit my original question.  Thank you.